# What exactly does presentModalViewController do?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

If I have a navigationController which is init with a root view controller MyViewController's instance.

And in that MyViewController's code
I can use

```
AnotherViewController *vc = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

or

```
AnotherViewController *vc = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I found these two works the same. Both present the modal view correctly.And I have found that the presented AnotherViewController's "parentViewController" property are all set to the navigation controller.

Why would this happen?the presentModalViewController automatically detect that the self is the subview of the navigation controller and re send the message to navigation controller?

Comment: Yes? Your MyViewController is a subview of the navigation controller (I think its in your code) if I am not mistaken, so no matter what you do it should pop up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Because MyViewController is the root view controller of the UINavigationController, it gets the convenience method of presentModalViewController: animated:  by default.  So when you say self.navigationController, it is referring to the same navigationController that presentModalViewController gives you.  I think Apple is just trying to make it more intuitive to use the convenience method.